# Servicestack Autoquery problems after update to 4.0.62

Tags: c#, servicestack, autoquery-servicestack

i have recently upgraded to ServiceStack v4.0.62

and now my project doesnt compile.
I have change my AutoQuery to IAutoQueryData but then none of my .Where and .Select and so on works anymore.

Please guide

[image]

If i leave it with IAutoQuery i get this error instead
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack introduced an alternative [AutoQuery Data implementation in v4.0.56](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.56.md) which lets you create [AutoQuery Services for alternative data sources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-Data#autoquery-data-sources) inc. Querying [In Memory Datasets](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-Memory), Querying Responses from [existing Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-Service) and Querying [DynamoDB](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-DynamoDB).

The [breaking changes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.56.md#autoquery-breaking-changes) section in v4.0.58 Release Notes covers the changes to AutoQuery which is now called `IAutoQueryDb` which should've also be listed in the [Obsolete message on the deprecated IAutoQuery interface](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/cce47fe3356cb71b7fd50eb654087f9f3b96a667/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs#L353-L354).

In summary, rename to `IAutoQueryDb` and if you're going to use `IAutoQuery` directly it's better if you pass in the entire `IRequest` as it will then be able to [participate in Multitenancy requests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.54.md#improved-support-for-multitenancy), so your query should now become:

```
public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

public object Get(ResourceTimeExceptionQuery request)
{ 
    var q = AutoQuery.Create(request, base.Request);
}
```

Comment: I had'nt got all the updates for Servicestack and thats why i didnt have the new Interface called IAutoQueryDb . Now it works. Thx!